# Grep rows from reference file while keeping the source column?

Tags: file, grep

I have two tables. Table 1 sample has multiple columns and table 2 has one column. My question is, how can i extract rows from table 1 based on values in table 1. I guess a simple grep should work but how can i do a grep on each row. I would like the output to retain the table 2 identifier that matched.

Thanks!

Desired Output:

```
IPI00004233 IPI00514755;IPI00004233;IPI00106646;    Q9BRK5-1;Q9BRK5-2;
IPI00001849 IPI00420049;IPI00001849;    Q5SV97-1;Q5SV97-2;
...
......
```

Table 1:

```
IPI00436567;    Q6VEP3;
IPI00169105;IPI01010102;    Q8NH21;
IPI00465263;    Q6IEY1;
IPI00465263;    Q6IEY1;
IPI00478224;    A6NHI5;
IPI00853584;IPI00000733;IPI00166122;    Q96NU1-1;Q96NU1-2;
IPI00411886;IPI00921079;IPI00385785;    Q9Y3T9;
IPI01010975;IPI00418437;IPI01013997;IPI00329191;    Q6TDP4;
IPI00644132;IPI00844469;IPI00030240;    Q494U1-1;Q494U1-2;
IPI00420049;IPI00001849;    Q5SV97-1;Q5SV97-2;
IPI00966381;IPI00917954;IPI00028151;    Q9HCC6;
IPI00375631;    P05161;
IPI00374563;IPI00514026;IPI00976820;    O00468;
IPI00908418;    E7ERA6;
IPI00062955;IPI00002821;IPI00909677;    Q96HA4-1;Q96HA4-2;
IPI00641937;IPI00790556;IPI00889194;    Q6ZVT0-1;Q6ZVT0-2;Q6ZVT0-3;
IPI00001796;IPI00375404;IPI00217555;    Q9Y5U5-1;Q9Y5U5-2;Q9Y5U5-3;
IPI00515079;IPI00018859;    P43489;
IPI00514755;IPI00004233;IPI00106646;    Q9BRK5-1;Q9BRK5-2;
IPI00064848;    Q96L58;
IPI00373976;    Q5T7M4;
IPI00375728;IPI86;IPI00383350;  Q8N2K1-1;Q8N2K1-2;
IPI01022053;IPI00514605;IPI00514599;    P51172-1;P51172-2;
```

Table 2:

```
IPI00000207
IPI00000728
IPI00000733
IPI00000846
IPI00000893
IPI00001849
IPI00002214
IPI00002335
IPI00002349
IPI00002821
IPI00003362
IPI00003419
IPI00003865
IPI00004233
IPI00004399
IPI00004795
IPI00004977
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use grep to prepend the needle, so no chance to use `-f file2`.

Use a loop and prepend manually:

```
while read token; do grep $token file1 |xargs -I{} echo $token {} ; done <file2
```

Alternatively, you could store both the results of `grep` and `grep -o` and `paste` them:

```
grep -f 2.txt 1.txt >a
grep -of 2.txt 1.txt >b
paste b a
```

---

If you're also fine with using `awk`, try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0];next } { for (x in a) if ($0 ~ x) print x, $0 }' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Explanation: For the first file (as long as `FNR==NR`), store all needles into array `a` (`{ a[$0];next }`). Then (implicitly) loop over all lines of the second file, loop again over all needles and print needle and line if found.

Comment: i like the awk solution. Thanks!